# R and MapReduce to find association rules

Tags: r, hadoop, mapreduce, arules

i'm at beginning with hadoop, i need to use it to calculate association rules of a very large dataset.
i can't understend how to use R Hadoop and MapReduce to find from a dataset association rules.
I have the transaction matrix but what i need to do to execute apriori algorithm with this matrix with hadoop??
this is the command used to execute apriori (package arules)

```
rules <- apriori(incidence.matrix , parameter = list(minlen=2, supp=0.09, conf=0.95))
```

i need to use it in map function on in reduce function?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem (R crashes with large data sets for arules), you can use **Mahout**, its a machine learning engine above Hadoop and it has **Association Rules** and other machine learning algorithms (like clustering .. etc.)